# JQuery Session problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery-session

I am using jQuery session in my master page. Anything I'm missing?

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.session("lnkID","A1")
});                   
</script>
```

> Error:
>   Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your example alone, you're missing a reference to the required files, and you're not wrapping your jQuery code in script tags. You need to reference not only [jquery-source](http://jquery.com), but [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/), and [jquery-session](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-session/) as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.json.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.session.js"></script>
```

Once you've got those in place, you need to place your logic within script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $.session("foo", "bar");
});
</script>
```

See the following demo for an example: http://www.jaysalvat.com/session/test1.html

Lastly, the `language` attribute of the `script` tag is deprecated. You can do away with it, but keep the `type` attribute.